# Qt stylesheet of dock area splitter

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

How to change the style sheet of splitter/handle beside QDockWidget when it is added to DockWidgetArea. There is one main movable handle and multiple handles between each dockwidgets on that side. I would like to change at least bg colour and border of the handle and hover colour.

It would help if I know what kind of object it is or to get some pointer to the handle to setStyleSheet on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I found it after some digging inside source code. Finally the answer was so simple and was screaming from the documentation of style sheet:

> Note: Use QMainWindow::separator to style the resize handle.

Ok so the code is simple:

```
QMainWindow::separator
{
    background-color: green;
    width: 4px;
    border: none;
}
```